# Conditional where-clause with Oracle and search order

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Imagine I have a big table t_order_items where each record has a record in t_order.
So, the columns are as follows:

t_order_item: order_item_id, order_id, item_name
t_order: order_id, order_name

Both order_id and order_name are unique, item_name often have lot’s of non-unique values in t_order_items.

Suppose I have a query which allows me to search orders by multiple item names and optionally limit search range with specific order names (depending on if I pass anything to filter_orders table).

```
with search_item_names as (select * from table (?)),
     filter_orders as (select * from table (?))
select order_id, order_name
from t_order_item oi
       join t_order o on (oi.order_id = o.order_id)
       join search_item_names sv on (sv.column_value = oi.item_name)
where (
          o.order_name in (select column_value from filter_orders)
         or not exists(select 1 from filter_orders)
          )
```

As you can see added this complex where-clause (to handle both empty and non-empty `filter_orders`):

```
where (o.order_name in (select column_value from filter_orders)
         or not exists(select 1 from filter_orders))
```

because I do not know beforehand if there will be any values passed in `filter_orders`.

The problem is that with such a complex where-clause it works slowly (because t_order_items is extremely huge):
* First searches for ALL order items with names from search_item_names
* Then filters out results by values in filter_orders

If I simplify where-clause like this:

```
where (o.order_name in (select column_value from filter_orders))
```

the query is executed much faster (and that's my performance goal), because it searches only for those order_items, which belong to specific orders defined in `filter_orders` (in other workds, it checks for order names first before joining all of order_items with `search_item_names`). But when I simplify where-clause, the new problem is: the query won’t find anything if `filter_orders` is empty.

Do I have any other options to conditionally match `o.order_name` with `filter_orders` and keep the performance by matching with `filter_orders` in the first place when `filter_orders` is not empty?

Comment: Use `union all` instead.